# Genre specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

Now I have tag privileges again, I've been trying to do my bit to help organise some questions. However, I did see a couple with very vague tags such as 'game-design'. Obviously this is fine, but it seems a little vague with just that and nothing else.
I thought about tagging it 'rpg' as well (since it was about RPG attack systems), then decided to ask here.

TL;DR Should questions be tagged with the genre they are about, if they are specific enough?

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense to me.  Tagging is supposed to be a community collaborative process, and if it makes sense then feel free to do it.  There are a few 'meta tags' that we've decided don't really belong (like "subjective"), but as long as the tag describes what is in the question instead of what kind of question it is, it should be fine.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/